# how to select all first td's inside all <tr> in to an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I need to get all the rows first td in to an javascript array and a do a check of if element exist in array print something.

can i please know how this can be done with jquery or javascript ?

I have created a fiddler here. http://jsfiddle.net/RXD2u/1/

```
<table id="tbl_dynamic_call_dates" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>07/10/2013</td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08/10/2013</td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>09/10/2013</td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell A</td>
        <td>Cell B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 1** I should ommit the first row and get all others. i tried an asnwer as given below but it doesnt ommit the first row.

```
var arr = $('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates tr td:first-child').map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get();
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? Please can you provide any code you have already tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var arr = $('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates tr:gt(0) td:first-child').map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

then use `$.inArray()` to test

like

```
var exists = ( $.inArray('08/10/2013', arr) != -1 );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/373eQ/)

Comment: Bow down to you master!!! In 2 mins you gave a complete solution which involves just 2 lines of code.

Comment: @Arun P tnx a lot. but i need to skip the first row and get all others. this is because i have defined a table header in my work and need to skip it. what i now get in the array is ["Appointment date", "07/10/2013", "08/10/2013", "10/10/2013", "11/10/2013"]

Comment: Mazraara, I dont think in that case any more changes to this code are required since the header is a string and will not match the date which you are cross checking

Comment: @Arun what does this retruns true or false ? var exists = ( $.inArray('08/10/2013', arr) != -1 ); i am asking weather ur check if exist or if not exists ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you pls reply on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178488/jquery-loop-through-all-the-rows-in-a-table-without-first-row

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$("table tr :first-child")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, this should work

```
$("tr td:first-child")
```

this will get you your first td's, then you can do whatever you want with them

Answer (score 0):

Use below code of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr").each(function(index,value){
     var val = $(this).find("td:first").text();
     alert(val);
  });
});
```

also include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("table tr td:first-child").each(function(index,value){
     var val = $(this).text();
     alert(val);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RXD2u/7/)**

Comment: You need to include jquery.