# Jquery loop through all the rows in a table without first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I need to loop through all rows for a particular table, and I have done it as below.  At one point, I need to remove the matching table row. I couldn't figure out how to skip the first row and loop through all others. My code below is looping through all tr's.

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr').each(
    function() {
        console.log($(this).find(\'td:first\').text());
        if($.inArray($(this).find(\'td:first\').text(),array) == -1){
            $(this).remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr').not(":first").  [....]
```

to get everything BUT the first

---

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr:first'). [...]
```

or

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr').first(). [...]
```

to only get the first

Answer (score 8):

Change your selector to this...

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr:not(:first)')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [`:gt() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) like:

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr:gt(0)').each(function() {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr:gt(0)').each(/*...*/);
```

Or:

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates > tbody  > tr').first().siblings().each(/*...*/);
```